# Reverse routing in Lumen. Call Router by it's name

Tags: php, routes, lumen, named-routing

I have some routes defined as below:

```
$app->get('/user/posts',  [
        "as"   => 'user.posts',
        "uses" => 'UserController@getPosts'
        ]);

$app->get('/user/ads',  [
        "as"   => 'user.ads',
        "uses" => 'UserController@getAds'
        ]);
```

It is possible to call these two routes by their name inside my third route (below)? Something like reverse routing?

```
$app->get('/user/all',  function() use ($app){
        /** This does not work
        $request = Request::create('MyRouteName', 'GET');
        // I can't use the Route class in Lumen
        $response = Route::dispatch($request);
        **/
        return [
             "posts" => Request::response_from('user.posts'),
             "ads"   => Request::response_from('user.ads')
        ];
});
```

I would like a method like `Request::response_from($routeNameOrUri)` that can get a the data from a route (by calling the controller's action)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you're having too much logic in your controllers where you could easily push this towards a model and have your router just point to different controller functions that bind to that model (in a sense).

Usually you want your router to not have inline functions as they cannot be cached and are much slower. Using facades is also a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

As I said before you're better off extracting whatever data you're retrieving into a user posts model and user ads model and having the controller action get what it needs.

```
/user/posts -> UserController@posts -> User->posts

/user/ads -> UserController@ads -> User->ads

/user/all -> UserController@all -> User->posts() & User->ads() or User->all()
```

If your goal is for this to be an api then I highly suggest looking into what RESTful routing is and good design guidelines.